# Gradle split "src/main/java" and "src/main/kotlin" into submodules

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

My project started with a single build.gradle (no multi-project). The project has `src/test/java` and `src/test/kotlin` folders.
So far, I have applied the configuration for both projects.

Main problem is the incompatibility with JDK 9 for `java` submodule and JDK 8 for `kotlin` submodule. With this error message

> Could not target platform: 'Java SE 9' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.

I want to apply:

- only to `src/test/java` a specific config (sourceCompatibility = 1.9)
- same to `src/test/kotlin` this config (kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8")

**How can I split both folders (java and kotlin) into submodules without moving files ?** The folders don't have to be split as submodules. I only want to apply different compilations options.

The project [**build.gradle** is there](https://github.com/raychenon/algorithms/blob/master/build.gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Use `sourceSets`

```
sourceSets {

                test {
                    kotlin {
                        srcDirs = ["src/test/kotlin"]
                    }
                    java {
                        srcDirs = ["src/test/java"]
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: can you be more precise how to apply a specific JDK version to them?

Comment: @RaymondChenon Can you show me the result of "gradle build -i"? I cannot replicate the error by only have build.gradle file.

Comment: The gradle file is linked above  https://github.com/raychenon/algorithms/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: @RaymondChenon Thing is I can run "gradle build" on my empty folder and it returned no error. So, only build.gradle file is not enough for me to replicate your problem.

Comment: clone the project and use `./gradlew build` at the root folder. Gradlew is the wrapper which uses the gradle version in the project. Whereas `gradle` command uses the version on your system.

Comment: @RaymondChenon I use OsX that have gradle-or-gradlew that can detect the gradlew in working dir and use it instead. Your build.gradle also has no wrapper section to indicate gradle version anyway. Look, I want to help you but I have no time to investigate the whole of your project.  Just give me the result of "gradlew build -i" which will indicate what task throw the error.

Comment: `> Task :compileJava FAILED
Caching disabled for task ':compileJava' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':compileJava' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has failed previously.
The input changes require a full rebuild for incremental task ':compileJava'.
:compileJava (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.009 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not target platform: 'Java SE 9' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.`

Comment: @RaymondChenon What is your JDK version? look like you use JDK 8 but want it to produce 9 ?

Comment: I use JDK version 1.12 , on IntelliJ the project level is JDK 9.  `src/main/kotlin` only supports up to JDK 8. But the `src/main/java` uses features in JDK 9 . It is described in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer how to run in IntelliJ, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58796344/311420

Basically, I was trying to use gradle configuration to run. But the tests fail in Intellij but not in gradle.
Now I run the tests with IntelliJ configurations not gradle.

It is half satisfactory answer.

You can see how my tests in [Circle CI](https://github.com/raychenon/algorithms/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml#L36) and [Travis CI](https://github.com/raychenon/algorithms/blob/master/.travis.yml#L25)