# Gradle unit tests not running

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, gradlew

I'm currently using a Gradle wrapper (version 4.10.1) on MacOS. The following issue occurred after I tried updating the wrapper to 6.8.2:

First of all, my unit tests were running fine before this. I used both intellij and the command line to run and build. The attempted wrapper upgrade didn't workout and I reverted the changes. I  ran `gradlew clean` and I even re-cloned the repo and built the repo from scratch.

The behaviors is that my tests are not running. They are *compiling* in the sense that invalid syntax will fail the build, but the tests are very obviously not running because adding something like `assertEquals(1,2)` will still succeed. Clicking the run button in intellij also gives me the message "test events were not received" and "Tests passed: 0".

I'm using junit 5.7.1, which worked perfectly before the attempted wrapper upgrade. Anyone else run into issues like this?

Comment: Have you tried any of these answers?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795263/test-events-were-not-received-when-run-tests-using-intellij

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with intellij since running gradle wrapper from the command line yields the same result

Comment: If there's a Gradle daemon running, have you tried killing/restarting it?

Comment: Yep tried. didn't work

Comment: try deleting gradle and .gradle folders from the project and rebuild the project.
in the project settings you can choose to run tests using intellij and not gradle (sometimes it works). I know it sounds trivial, but make sure you imported junit 5 as @Test and not junit 4 or something else.